# Vk Api JS проблема при выходе из функции

Tags: javascript, вконтакте, vkontakte-api

Имеется вот такой кусок кода:

```
function GroupMembers1(data){
        GroupCount1=data.response.count;
        var a=0;
        for(var i=0;i<=GroupCount1; i++){
        VK.api("users.get", {user_ids:data.response.users[i], fields:"sex"}, function(data){
                if(data.response[0].sex==1){
                    GroupMember1[a]=data.response.users[i]; 
                    a++;

                };
            });
        };
    };
```

В нем имеется массив GroupMember1, и после выхода из функции, он очищается, ну все значения становятся undefined. Сам массив заведен раньше.

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что после выхода из функции запросы не успевают пройти и обработаться. В этом и причина.

Comment: Ну в самой функции, в массив все записывается, то есть причина наверное в другом.

Comment: Это асинхронные вызовы. У апи имею в виду.

Comment: Хм, и что тогда предлагаешь делать?

Comment: вот опять то-же самое... видите там i и a ? в асинхронной функции  этот i будет последним вызванным, а "a" перемещается с большой верояностью. всем настоятельно рекомендую читать http://hashcode.ru/questions/272864#272867

Comment: кроме того, вам видимо надо знать когда все вызовы закончатся, для этого удобно использовать обратный счетчик от GroupCount1 до 0 и в случае 0  вызывать функцию которая ждет заполненный массив  GroupMember1

Answer (score 1):

Суммируя, получается что-то типа такого:

```
function GroupMembers1(data) {
    var GroupCount1 = data.response.count,
        GroupMember1 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i <= GroupCount1; i++) {
        VK.api("users.get", {
            user_ids: data.response.users[i],
            fields: "sex"
        }, handleUser(i));
    }

    function handleUser(i) {
        return function (data1) { //тут была ещё одна ошибка, вы переопределяли родительскую data новым значением, я поставил data1 чтобы разделить
            if (data1.response[0].sex == 1) {
                GroupMember1.push(data.response.users[i]);
            }               
            if (GroupCount1==i) continuegroups(GroupMember1);
        };
    }
}

function continuegroups(GroupMember1) {
    console.log(GroupMember1); //тут должен выводиться массив собранный в коллбэке  вызова api, ещё момент - функция не вызовется если коллбэк сработает меньшее число раз, чем GroupCount1 (например в результате ошибки)
}
```